# How to programmatically get a Rails Routes constraint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to collect all the Rails routes, and dump their `named_route`, `path` and `constraint` (if there is one).

I'm able to get the `named_route`, `path`, but I'm trying to find a way to get the routes `constraint`.

```
routes = Rails.application.routes.routes.map do |route|
 path = route.path.spec.to_s.gsub!("(.:format)", '')

 # route.constraints always output {} ??
 puts route.constraints

 name = route.name
 [name, path]
end.to_h
```

Here is an example of a route..

```
USER_NAME_PATTERN ||= /@[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+/
get ":username/:slug", to: 'calcs#show', as: :user_calc , constraints: {username: USER_NAME_PATTERN }
```

How to programmatically get a Rails Routes constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints are a bit complicated, because there are multiple kinds of route constraint, which are specified the same way in `routes.rb`, but get handled internally somewhat differently.

The kind of constraint in your question is a [segment constraint](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints), which imposes a format on one or more segments of the path. Segment constraints are stored in the `requirements` hash at the path level, using keys that correspond to the segment names (segment names are stored in the `parts` attribute on the `Route`).

```rb
> route = Rails.application.routes.named_routes.get(:user_calc)
=> #<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x00007f6aa05b2cc0>
> route.parts
=> [:username, :slug, :format]
> route.path.requirements
=> {:username=>/@[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+/}
```

There are also [request constraints](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints), which constrains a route based on any method on the `Request` object that returns a string. These get specified similarly to segment constraints:

```rb
get ":username/:slug", to: 'calcs#show', as: :user_calc , constraints: {subdomain: 'admin'}
```

Request constraints are stored in the `constraints` attribute on the `Route` object.

```rb
> route = Rails.application.routes.named_routes.get(:user_calc)
=> #<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x00007f6aa05b2cc0>
> route.constraints
=> {:subdomain=>"admin"}
```

You can also specify constraints using a `lambda` or class that responds to `.matches?`. These advanced constraints seem to be handled by a different mechanism, but I haven't dug around enough in the code to understand exactly how.